# I want to merge mp3 files on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, concatenation, mp3

I want to merge mp3 files into one file using this command :

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:file_1.mp3|file_2.mp3|file_3.mp3|file_4.mp3" -c copy test.mp3
```

But i get this error :

```
[mp3 @ 0x5629416b4880] Invalid audio stream. Exactly one MP3 audio stream is required.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

I tried to use cat and mp3wrap but it only duplicates the first file

I would like to mention that the mp3 files are a recorded ones using pyaudio

**Edit :**
i used this command :

```
ffmpeg -y -i "concat:file_1.mp3|file_2.mp3|file_3.mp3|file_4.mp3" test.mp3
```

and it seems to be working but it only duplicates the first file not merging the

files.

Command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "concat:39492fr_man_1.mp3|39492fr_man_2.mp3|39492fr_man_3.mp3|39492fr_man_4.mp3" 39492_fr_man.mp3
```

**The output:**

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : mono
Input #0, wav, from 'concat:39492fr_man_1.mp3|39492fr_man_2.mp3|39492fr_man_3.mp3|39492fr_man_4.mp3':
  Duration: 00:04:40.06, bitrate: 2460 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp3, to '39492_fr_man.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, mono, s16p
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libmp3lame
size=    2188kB time=00:04:40.05 bitrate=  64.0kbits/s speed= 134x
video:0kB audio:2188kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.010131%
```

**Command :** `ffmpeg -i 39492fr_man_1.mp3 -i 39492fr_man_2.mp3 -i 39492fr_man_3.mp3 -i 39492fr_man_4.mp3`

**Output:**

```
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : mono
Input #0, wav, from '39492fr_man_1.mp3':
  Duration: 00:04:40.06, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : mono
Input #1, wav, from '39492fr_man_2.mp3':
  Duration: 00:04:40.54, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #2.0 : mono
Input #2, wav, from '39492fr_man_3.mp3':
  Duration: 00:04:39.50, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #2:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #3.0 : mono
Input #3, wav, from '39492fr_man_4.mp3':
  Duration: 00:02:16.42, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #3:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: Show the **complete** output of `ffmpeg -i file_1.mp3 -i file_2.mp3 -i file_3.mp3 -i file_4.mp3`

Comment: @llogan i updated the problem, please consider checking it

Comment: @llogan the output is a file called 39492_fr_man.mp3, otherwise i don't understand what do u mean

Comment: @llogan i've added the output of the command

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You inputs are not actually MP3. These are actually WAV files named as MP3. So you can't use `-c copy`. You can't copy pcm_s16le ("WAV") into MP3, so that's why you got the `Invalid audio stream` error.

The concat protocol is almost useless. Use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) or the [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat). It doesn't matter which one you use in this case, so use whichever is more convenient for you.

### concat demuxer

1. Make `input.txt` containing:

   ```
   file '39492fr_man_1.mp3'
   file '39492fr_man_2.mp3'
   file '39492fr_man_3.mp3'
   file '39492fr_man_4.mp3'
   ```
2. Concatenate:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt output.mp3
   ```

### concat filter

```
ffmpeg -i 39492fr_man_1.mp3 -i 39492fr_man_2.mp3 -i 39492fr_man_3.mp3 -i 39492fr_man_4.mp3 -filter_comples "[0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a]concat=n=4:a=1:v=0" output.mp3
```

Comment: god bless you, it's working now, i have a question if the files are .wav (because i do record the audio in mp3 format so i can use .wav) the first command is going to work fine with me?

Comment: @AdilKasbaoui You can use WAV as inputs for both the concat demuxer and the concat filter. For concat demuxer all inputs must be the same format (such as wav), same sample rate (such as 44100), same channel layout (such as stereo).